# JavaScript function call inside the html tag

Tags: javascript

As i understand when we invoke a method `this` contains reference to `object` which invoke this method. But what is an "object" and a "method" in the following case:

Consider `html` code snippet

```
<div id="parent">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="doThis(this)"/>
</div>
```

where `doThis()` is `JS` function, such that

```
doThis(obj){
    obj.style.background="#ff00ff"
}
```

I know, that `this` will be contained reference to `submit` button, but i dont understand why.

Comment: What would you expect it to be?

Comment: Please stop using inline js. https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Comment: A great reference to learn basically everything about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html):

> When an event handler content attribute is set
>
> ...
>
> create a function object (as defined in ECMAScript edition 5 section 13.2 Creating Function Objects)
>
> ...
>
> Set the corresponding event handler to the aforementioned function

and

> Process the Event object `E` as follows:
>
> ...
>
> Invoke callback with one argument, the value of which is the Event object `E`, with the callback `this` value set to `E`'s currentTarget.